# How to get the foreground window on Windows?

Tags: winapi, window

Windows API has a method called `GetForegroundWindow`.
But it considers the Desktop as a foreground window when you click on it.
We all know that when it happens the previous foreground window isn't superposed by it.
How to get the real foreground window handle?

Comment: Suppose you have two visible windows over the desktop.  Which one is the "real" foreground window after you click on the desktop?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve.  Your question, as written, does not make sense.

Comment: This is certainly not normal behavior, never seen this on any of my machines.  Beware of 'add-ons' that try to emulate a desktop.

Comment: I removed the `GetForegroundWindow` tag, since we really don't want to have a tag for every win-api method. Revert if you think the tag is still appropriate.

Comment: @Peter I want to know if I need to flash the taskbar icon indicating an update, or if the user is already seeing the update

Comment: @Hans I don't have any desktop related software in my machine that I'm aware of. Try double clicking in a desktop icon and see if that changes the Foreground Window to the desktop.

Comment: @Juliet Your edit is reasonable, I don't know what are the community guidelines concerning this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overengineering your solution.  If your application window is not the foreground window when you receive an update, then flash the window.  The point of flashing is to capture the user's attention, and you have no way to determine if you have their attention programmatically.

It seems like what you really want to know is: "Is the portion of my window that changes currently visible to the user?"  That's quite a complex question to answer, and even if you answer it correctly, you have no way to know if the user will notice the change.

Comment: I just want to implement it, because I tested another application (Google Talk) and it works as I describe.

Comment: @Jader: even if you're determined to do this, finding the "foreground" window isn't the way to go - as Peter noted in his comment on your question, there may be more than one (and they may not be obscuring *your* window anyway). If you just want to know if the user can *see* your window, I suspect examining the clipping region (for **your** window) is the way to go... but that's a topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Both the "desktop" (Explorers desktop listview on top of the real desktop window) and the taskbar are real windows where the user might be "working" (Tab'ing around, using menus etc)

If you want to find the "real" foreground window that bad you have find it yourself, your best bet is going for the window at the top of the z-order, maybe something like:

```
... enumfunc(hwnd,...) 
{
    if (GetClassName(hwnd)!= "Shell_TrayWnd")
    {
        if (IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) && IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && GetWindow(hwnd,GW_OWNER)==NULL)
        {
            DoSomethingWithRealForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            return FALSE
        }
    }
}

EnumWindows(enumfunc,0)
```

[TaskSwitchXP](http://www.ntwind.com/download/TaskSwitchXP_2.0.11-src.zip) is a open source alt-tab replacement, it probably has a better algorithm that you can use...